# How to check if a windows app is running in full screen mode in python

Tags: python

how to check if app is in full screen mode or in windows mode ?

I am using `process.Popen("wmplayer.exe", video.mp4)` to  open the file.
Then, `pyautogui.hotkey("alt","enter")` to switch to full screen.

How to verify whether the app is in full screen mode ?
For example like screen size or resolution ?